# Reverse Stone-Weierstrass theorem

Tags: general-topology

In my book for topology, the Stone-Weierstrass theorem is:

*Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space. Then any point-seperating real subalgebra $\mathcal{A}\subset \mathcal{C}(X,\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $(\mathcal{C}(X,\mathbb{R}),d_{\sup})$.*

Now I have this exercise, with $X$ compact Hausdorff space, $\mathcal{C}(X)$ the space of real-valued continuous functions on $X$ and we use the metric $d_{\sup}(f,g)=\|f-g\|_{\sup}$. I have to prove that **if $\mathcal{A}\subset C(X)$ is a dense subset of $C(X)$, then $\mathcal{A}$ must be point-seperating.**

I was thinking to prove this with contraposition, so I would assume $\mathcal{A}$ is not point-seperating. But then I don't know what to do next.

Who can help me? :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Since $X$ is compact Hausdorff, it’s normal. Given distinct $x,y\in X$, apply Uryson’s lemma to get $f\in\mathscr{C}(X)$ such that $f(x)=0$ and $f(y)=1$. Now consider functions very close to $f$ in the metric $d_\sup$.

Comment: This hint is helping me already, but can you help me with the second part?  Consider $g\in C(X)$ such that $\|f-g\|\leq \epsilon$, for $\epsilon>0$. What is next?

Comment: @JBIBB: Can you see how to take $\epsilon$ small enough so that $g(0)$ cannot be equal to $g(1)$?

Comment: Choose $\epsilon >0$ such that $\|g(x)-f(x)\| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for $x=0,1$. Then $\|f(1)-f(0)\|\leq \|f(1)-g(1)\|+\|g(1)-g(0)\|+\|g(0)-f(0)\| \leq \epsilon + \|g(1)-g(0)\|$. But we know by Uryson's lemma that $f(1)\neq f(0)$, so this states that $g(0)$ can not be equal to $g(1)$. Thus for every $x,y\in X, x\neq y$, one can find $f\in \mathcal{A}$ such that $f(x)\neq f(y)$. $\mathcal{A}$ is thus point-seperating. This leaves me one more question: where did I use that $\mathcal{A}$ is dense in $C(X)$?

Comment: @JBIBB: Not quite: if your $\epsilon$ were $100$, say, it would be entirely possible to have $g(0)=g(1)$ and $d_\sup(f,g)\le 50$. But if you have a $g$ such that $d_\sup(f,g)<\frac{1}2$, then $|f(0)-g(0)|<\frac{1}2$, and $|f(1)-g(1)|<\frac{1}2$, so $g(0)<\frac{1}2<g(1)$. The fact that $\mathscr{A}$ is dense in $C(X)$ ensures that for any $\epsilon>0$, $\mathscr{A}\cap B(f,\epsilon)\ne\varnothing$.

Comment: ooh okay! Thank you very much!

Comment: @JBIBB: You're welcome!